# Provide metrics for Business Discovery insights in Instagram Graph API

Tags: facebook-graph-api, instagram, instagram-graph-api

I was creating an application to get insights into business and creator accounts. But when I was trying out to get insights of an account using business discovery, I was receiving the error

```
{
  "error": {
    "message": "(#100) For field 'insights': The parameter metric is required",
    "type": "OAuthException",
    "code": 100,
    "fbtrace_id": "A_VNXOMovZwvUpzUFVF5y87"
  }
}
```

The query I fetched was `?fields=business_discovery.username(google){insights{impressions}}`

I know how can I fetch insights data for my account `/insights?metric=impressions&period=day`. But I cannot understand, how can I give the `period` argument in that previous query?

Answer (score 1):

Business discovery cannot get insight data.
You should use insight api instead.

Here's a simple account insight fyr
17841403823915540/insights/?metric=follower_count,reach,impressions&period=day&since2021-01-11&until=2021-01-18

And you will get sth like:

```
{
  "data": [
    {
      "name": "follower_count",
      "period": "day",
      "values": [
        {
          "value": 0,
          "end_time": "2021-01-16T08:00:00+0000"
},
```

Comment: How to get other page's insights data? I think based on instagram develop docs it could be possible.

Answer (score 0):

It is not possible to query insights of other instagram accounts with [insights](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/instagram-api/reference/ig-user/insights) or [business_discovery](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/instagram-api/reference/ig-user/business_discovery) endpoint. I have come to conclusion that you have to use `business_discovery` endpoint together with `media` edge and calculate insights yourself.